# Does "prior word" means "information about something that is going to happen" in some contexts?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm confused by a phrase "prior word" in an article. Does this phrase means something like "information" or "military intelligence" about something that is going to happen? Such as in the sentence "FDR didn't have prior word of Pearl Harbor".

Comment: It's a formal expression, and fairly rare, but definitely not confined to military intelligence. Google something like "prior word about".

Comment: Short Answer: Yes. Long Answer: But as Edwin Ashworth mentions, it's not only confined to military intelligence.

Comment: It depends greatly on the context.  In the above it would be taken to mean "information before the event".  There is no strong association with military or "intelligence" meanings.  Eg, the "victim" of a surprise birthday party is not given "prior word" of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of *word* is

> news; tidings; information: *We received word of his death.* ([Dictionary.com #7](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/word))

The phrase "send word" is quite common, as in

> Send word to the main office that we are low on paperclips.

It simply means to inform, report, or send news.

The phrase *receive word* is also common, as in

> Thomas, we have received word that you are low on paperclips. It that true?

Of course this means to receive information or news.

You can see where this is going.

> Thomas is here demanding paperclips. I've had no prior word of this. Why wasn't I informed?